# Overloading __divmod__ method not working as expected

Tags: python-2.7

I added a `__divmod__` method to a custom class. However, when I call the divmod function on an instance of this class, an extra `None` is returned along with the (div, mod) tuple.

Here is a minimal example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __divmod__(self, other):
        return np.divmod(self.val, other)

m = MyClass(7)
```

Calling `divmod(m, 5)` gives:

```
((1, 2), None)
```

whereas I expected the result to be the same as calling `m.__divmod__(5)` directly:

```
(1, 2)
```

I don't understand where the extra `None` comes from. Maybe the magic method `__divmod__` has another purpose? Can somebody provide an example?

Comment: my test in Python 2 & 3, `divmod(m, 5)` both output: `(1, 2)`?

Comment: What Python-2 version are you using? I tested 2.7.13 and 2.7.15 on two different computers (both Anaconda distribution).

Comment: I used jupyter python2 kernel: 2.7.13, my usual environment is python3, it is only I  got

Comment: Thanks for testing. It sounds like there is a specific problem with my python environment.

Comment: OK, I found the solution. The problem occurred in an IPython session where the divmod function was actually overwritten by numpy's divmod. Using the python divmod function yields the expected result. Unfortunately, I'm not able to answer my own question and mark it as solved.

Comment: I remember you can answer your own question, but I haven't tried.